# How to determine if one checkbox on a datagridview is checked and if all are unchecked

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a DataGridView containing Check boxes in the first column.

I need to check if only one check box has been checked or if there are no boxes checked.

Looping though the DataGridView will give me true and false as each box becomes checked and unchecked, which is what I have attempted with the code below.

I need to create a Method which will return true if one of the box is check and false if no box is checked.

I tried this: Calling it in and experiment is different related DataGridView click event.

```
Public Function IsContainChecked() As Boolean

    Dim ch1 As New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell()
    ch1 = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0),  _
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    Return CBool(ch1.EditingCellFormattedValue)

End Function
```

Comment: why do you need to direct cast the object?

Comment: Don't `new` something only to reassign it on the next line. Seeing way too much of that lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim checkedCount = DataGridView1.Rows.
                                 Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().
                                 Where(Function(row) Not row.IsNewRow).
                                 Count(Function(row) CBool(row.Cells(0).Value))

Select Case checkedCount
    Case 0
        'No rows are checked.
    Case 1
        'One row is checked.
    Case Else
        'More than one row is checked.
End Select
```

You can put that code in a method and call it wherever you like, e.g. in the `CellValueChanged` event handler.  Just note that the `Value` of a check box cell does not change immediately when you click it.  The documentation for the event addresses that and explains what to do if you want to force the `Value` to change on a click.

Comment: And... ***how does this explain the OP's issue***? Throwing an answer up without explanation of the original post is helpless as the OP does not understand where they have a problem...

Comment: @Codexer, given that the OP has accepted the answer, I guess you could ask them that question.